# mhchem latex package in pandoc to docx

Tags: html, latex, docx, pandoc

I'm trying to convert an html, that contains math (rendered by MathJax) to docx using pandoc. Everything is well with regular math, but equations where mhchem package is used aren't rendered. Is there a way to force pandoc to use certain LaTeX packages during conversion?

I use this command:

pandoc -f html+tex_math_single_backslash lab4.html -o lab4.docx